# Var in 'IF' statement - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this `if` statement:

```
if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
        (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
    $element.addClass('.slide');
} else {
    $element.removeClass('slide');
}
```

I want, instead of addClass/removeClass, to add a previously created `var` (ex. `add($slideObjects)`, `remove($slideObjects)`. Is this possible and what is the correct syntax to make it happen?

Comment: Why does `addClass('.slide')` have a `.` in the class name?

Comment: Ups, mistake in the example. But the question remains: how to add 'var' instead of a class?

Comment: You have tried `$element.addClass(yourVariable);`, right?

Comment: That seems like a strange condition. How can the bottom position of an element be higher than the top of the window and have the element's top position be lower than the bottom of the window at the same time?

Comment: I'm checking to see if each item's bottom position is greater than the top position of the window but also that the item’s top position is less than the bottom position of the window, so I can scroll from top to bottom and reverse and the effect will work both ways.

Comment: @squint I think it roughly means “if the bottom of the element is below the top of the window and the top of the element is above the bottom of the window”, or in other words: “if the element is visible in the window”, although using `<=` and `>=` instead of `<` and `>` may not have the correct semantics for that.

Comment: @Xufox I tried using your suggestion, didn't work. By the way, where is the mistake in using <= and >= instead of < and >?

Comment: @Xufox: Yeah, I assume that's what the OP is aiming for, but it sure looks like they have the comparison operators reversed. It's early here, so maybe my brain isn't awake, but it sure reads to me like the element must be both above and below the window, and not inside, which wouldn't be possible. But if it works for the OP, then it works.

Comment: @Xufox: Nope, it's my early waking brain at fault. I was interpreting "greater than" as higher positionally, yet numerically it's lower, and vice versa. Sorry for the distraction GjoreDz.

Comment: @GjoreDz Whether using `<=` and `>=` really is a mistake, depends on the exact use case, but for example if the bottom of the element is exactly the top of the window, it’s probably not visible, although your condition maybe should only apply if it’s visible. As I said, it depends…

Comment: @Xufox Yes, you are right. Thanks for clearing that out :)

Comment: Is `$slideObjects` referencing DOM elements that are to be added and removed? If so, have you tried `$slideObjects.appendTo($element)` and `$slideObjects.remove()`?